# Change immediate previous icon on same level when collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I've three collapsible elements, each one with its header and a button for collapse it. I'm using [Material Design](https://material.io/icons/) icons for the button icon.

```
<div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
    <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
        <p class="h4">
            <i class="material-icons md-36">turned_in_not</i> Documento
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDetails" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <i class="material-icons" >remove_circle_outline</i>
            </button>
        </p>
        <hr class="mb-4" style="background-color:#169db2"> 
        <div class="collapse show" id="collapseDetails" style="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="DOCUMENTNUMBER">Número</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">insert_drive_file</i></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-control border-info alert-info text-center">001-10-0-10459</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="TITLE">Título</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">book</i></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">PINTURA RAMPA AGAETE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="INSTALLATION">Instalación</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">directions_boat</i></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-control border-info text-center">COMPAÑIA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="DEPARTMENT">Departamento</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">view_quilt</i></span>
                        </div>
                            <span class="form-control border-info">MAINTENANCE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="CONFIRMATIONDATE">Fecha de Confirmación</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">today</i></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="form-control border-info">-</span>
                        </div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="SUPPLIER">Proveedor</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">local_shipping</i></span>
                        </div>
                            <span class="form-control border-info">JOTUN IBERICA, S.A.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="PRIORITY">Prioridad</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">error_outline</i></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="form-control border-info text-center">N/A</span>
                        </div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="BUDGET">Presupuesto</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text border-info"><i class="material-icons color-info">card_travel</i></span>
                        </div>
                            <span class="form-control border-info">120425 - Mantenimiento Rampas TCI</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p class="h4">
            <i class="material-icons md-36">place</i> Entrega
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm float-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDelivery" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i>
            </button>
        </p>
        <hr class="mb-4" style="background-color:#169db2">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseDelivery" style="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="location">Ubicación</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <label for="address2">Dirección de Entrega<span class="text-muted"></span></label>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="country">País</label>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                            <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                    <label for="contact">Contacto</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="phone">Teléfono</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                    <label for="DeliveryDate">Email</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="DeliveryDate">Condiciones de Entrega</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p class="h4">
            <i class="material-icons md-36">credit_card</i> Facturación
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseInvoice" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i>
            </button>
        </p>
        <hr class="mb-4" style="background-color:#169db2">


        <div class="collapse" id="collapseInvoice">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="DeliveryDate">Nombre</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">Customer S.A.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label for="DeliveryDate">Términos de Pago</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="address2">Dirección de Facturación<span class="text-muted"></span></label>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <span class="form-control border-info">POL. IND. AÑAZA, SN</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <span class="form-control border-info">EDIFICIO</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <span class="form-control border-info">CP 38111 SC DE TENERIFE</span>
                    </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="country">País</label>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                            <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                    <label for="contact">Contacto</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="phone">Teléfono</label>
                        <span class="form-control border-info">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm stucked on changing the icon of the button for the element what it's collapsed or expanded by using jQuery.

Supposedly i should change the immediate previous icon on same level with `.prev()` but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this)
                .prevAll()
                .find("button")
                .find(".material-icons")
                .text("remove_circle_outline");
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this)
                .prevAll()
                .find("button")
                .find(".material-icons")
                .text("add_circle_outline");
        });
});
```

I also tried to use `.prevAll()` but then it's changing all previous icons at the same level.

What can i do to change only the button icon of the element which is being collapsed or expanded?

This is a [**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cjxqm3vw/) showing my problem.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to change icons on the left of "Documento", "Entrega" etc?

Comment: @WebDevBooster No. I want to change the button iccon on the right of "Documento", "Entrega" etc

Comment: But it's already changing from plus to minus.

Comment: But the previous icons are being also changed when collapsing the second and third element

Comment: @WebDevBooster I mean, First icon is also changed when i collapse/expand the second element. Same behavior for the third element which is also changing the first and second icon.

Comment: since your element dont have parent. you can replace `prevAll()` with `prev().prev()` https://jsfiddle.net/cjxqm3vw/42/ but the right way is you can use some attribute like `data-target="spesificButtonIdentifier"`

Comment: I missed my element parent. That's it! Thanks @plonknimbuzz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("[data-target='#"+ $(this).attr('id') +"']")` to select button with the `data-target` of the clicked collapse.

Here is the working code. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjxqm3vw/36/)

Comment: hei equisde. this is the right way for the alternative of dirty `prev().prev()`

Comment: Great! It's working like a charm. Thank tou so much!